# Table layout design issue in Firefox browser

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I have a table in my html page, in the table the first tr has images and next tr has text  and it look's good in IE and Chrome browser's like this

[image]

but when I use in Firefox browser it looks like this:

[image]

I just used CSS (text-align:center) for td and (border-collapse: collapse,width: 100%) for table that's all...

**My html code:**

```
<table class="foottable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="foottabcen"><img id="check" src="images/unchecked.png"/></td>
                    <td class="foottabcen"><img id="export" class="image1" src="images/excelicon.png" /></td>
                    <td class="foottabcen"><img id="test" class="image1" src="images/mailicon.png" /></td>
                    <td class="foottabcen"><img id="sms" class="image2" src="images/smsicon.png"/></td>
                    <td class="foottabcen"><a href="admin_chart.jsp" id="graph"><img class="image1" src="images/charticon.png" /></a></td>
                    <td class="foottabcen"><img id="print" class="image1" src="images/printericon.png"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="foottabcen">Select all</td>
                    <td class="foottabcen">Export to excel</td>
                    <td class="foottabcen">Mail</td>
                    <td class="foottabcen">SMS</td>
                    <td class="foottabcen">Graph</td>
                    <td class="foottabcen">Print</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**My CSS code:**

```
.foottable
{
    width: 100%;border-top: 2px solid #D4D4D4;border-collapse: collapse;background: white;
}
.foottabcen
{
    color:black;text-align: center;
}
```

please help me.........

Comment: Have you tried debugging it via Right click > "Inspect element" in Firefox? If you check the styles applied, this may give you more information.

Comment: Give the fix height for TD......

Comment: now see it i have did some changes

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would want to do this way but I guess the better way would have been putting the image and text in the same td like:

```
<td>
 <a href="#">
   <span><img src="images/exl_icon.png" alt="" /></span>
   <small>Export to excel</small>
 </a> 
</td> /* <a> is added considering these are clickable elements */
```

and apply `display:block;` to 'a', 'span' and 'small' through your css.

and probably the best way would have been just use text as link in the td and add a icon specific class to it:

```
<td>
 <a href="#" class="ico_excel">Export to excel</a>
</td>
```

and in your css it will look like this:

```
 .ico_excel{
    display:block; 
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: x px; /* x should be more than the height of the icon */
    background: transparent url(images/exl_icon.png) center top no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: but i need the a tag only for graph and for design alignment i used two tr in table

Comment: You can remove <a> tags wherever they aren't required in first example and replace it by span in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <table class="foottable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <td class="foottabcen"><img id="check" src="images/unchecked.png"/></td>
                <td class="foottabcen"><img id="export" class="image1" src="images/excelicon.png" /></td>
                <td class="foottabcen"><img id="test" class="image1" src="images/mailicon.png" /></td>
                <td class="foottabcen"><img id="sms" class="image2" src="images/smsicon.png"/></td>
                <td class="foottabcen"><a href="admin_chart.jsp" id="graph"><img class="image1" src="images/charticon.png" /></a></td>
                <td class="foottabcen"><img id="print" class="image1" src="images/printericon.png"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="foottabcen1">Select all</td>
                <td class="foottabcen1">Export to excel</td>
                <td class="foottabcen1">Mail</td>
                <td class="foottabcen1">SMS</td>
                <td class="foottabcen1">Graph</td>
                <td class="foottabcen1">Print</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and css...give height for foottabcen as per ur requirement

```
 .foottable
 {
     width: 100%;border-top: 2px solid #D4D4D4;border-collapse: collapse;
     background: white;
   }
 .foottabcen
 {
     color:black;text-align: center;height:50px;
    }
   .foottabcen1
{
color:black;text-align: center;
  }
```

check demo here..... http://jsfiddle.net/dBFfd/

Comment: check in demo ...and give different height as your requirement

Comment: what problem giving next tr

Answer (score 1):

did you try this...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img id="check" src="images/unchecked.png"/>
            <span>sample</span>
        </td>
    </tr
</table>
```

but if you want my free assistant just email your code i try to fix it....